# What is the difference between the digital download and the boxed version of Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

What I know so far is that the boxed version should include free guest pass tickets. Is there anything in addition (except for the box, the CD/DVD and probably a printed user guide)?

Comment: I bought the boxed version and the DVD was blank! Luckily they let you download the software if you have a key. There is nothing valuable in the box in my opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The boxed version contains the following:

- 1 DVD copy of Starcraft II
- 1 Game manual
- 1 Pad of notepaper (For your
  build orders I'm guessing)
- 2 World of
  Warcraft 10 day guest passes
- 2 Starcraft II 7 hour guest passes

The digital version obviously only allows you to download, install and play the game.

Answer (score 5):

> ... In short there are no differences between the digital download version of StarCraft II and the one in the boxed version, with the Blizzard rep saying, "All the files are exactly the same, but you obviously don't get the box, DVD, or manual." Also, If you get a boxed copy of the game and add the included key into your Battle.net account, "the option to download the client online will become available." The game client is region-specific, however. As the Blizzard rep explains, "Therefore, in order for a player to log in and begin playing, both the StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty game license and the installed game client must be from the same region. If the game license and the game client don't match, the player will be unable to login."

According to [this post](http://news.bigdownload.com/2010/07/21/starcraft-ii-forums-answer-questions-about-game-activation/), the answer is from a Blizzard developer

Comment: He doesn't include the lack of guest passes (for SC2 or WoW), so I'm not sure how much I trust this quote.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the fact that with the boxed version you have a physical disc, manual and a box, there's no game content differences between the boxed and digital download versions of the game.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy the boxed collectors addition, you get some extra swag, including Starcraft 1. You also get a "Feat of Strength" if you buy the collectors edition.

Comment: lol wow an achievement.. I bet some ppl buy the collectors addition just for that.

Comment: Ya, I was pretty pissed Blizzard did that. It's called the "dedicated-fan" achievement. Which of course is slightly insulting to people who are hard core dedicated fans, but simply can't afford the additional $50. /sarcasm Guess they aren't dedicated enough!

Comment: I bought the boxed collector's edition and I didn't get Starcraft 1 with it.

Comment: It's actually a "Feat of Strength" which is worth no achievement points. Blizzard has done this kind of stuff tons of times before, like in WoW you can retain feats of strength for completing raids, quests, or obtaining items that are no longer available.

Comment: @Carl Clover Starcraft 1 is pre-loaded on the jump drive that you got with the collector's edition

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the "game manual" some are referring to is just a quick-start guide.  It has some artwork and 19 pages of text, consisting of:

- 4 pages of requirements/installation/etc.
- 9 pages of SC1 story recap (which you'll already know if you played SC1)
- 6 pages of EULA

All the detailed game information is online at battle.net.  You're not missing anything by not having this manual unless you're dying to read the story recap.

Comment: Actually, I only just noticed that a PDF of the quick-start guide installs with the game.  So by downloading, you're not missing any content at all; all you're missing is a hard copy.